# Expose container DNS to another container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Using Docker Compose and Traefik, I am trying to have the application container communicate to the solr container and vice versa in a local environment.

Currently, I can access both the application and the solr URL in the browser just fine, but they cannot 'see' or talk to one another internally.

I am new with Docker. Here is a section of my docker compose file with the relevant containers:

```
php:
    image: wodby/drupal-php:$PHP_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_php"
    environment:
      PHP_SENDMAIL_PATH: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -S mailhog:1025
      DB_HOST: $DB_HOST
      DB_USER: $DB_USER
      DB_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
      DB_NAME: $DB_NAME
      DB_DRIVER: $DB_DRIVER
      PHP_FPM_USER: wodby
      PHP_FPM_GROUP: wodby
      COLUMNS: 80 
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html:cached

  solr:
    image: wodby/solr:$SOLR_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_solr"
    environment:
      SOLR_DEFAULT_CONFIG_SET: $SOLR_CONFIG_SET
      SOLR_HEAP: 1024m
    labels:
      - 'traefik.backend=${PROJECT_NAME}_solr'
      - 'traefik.port=8983'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:solr.${PROJECT_BASE_URL}'


  traefik:
    image: traefik
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_traefik"
    command: -c /dev/null --web --docker --logLevel=INFO
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '8983:8983'
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

I can access Solr at the given URL, but the application cannot see it at the same URL. I need to be able to do this so it can talk to Solr and have it crawl/etc.

Is there a way to expose them so they can see each other by their hostname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker-compose` has container DNS resolution built-in. You can `expose` a specific port on your container to enable access within the docker network, or define `port` (as you have done for your traefik container) to expose it both within the docker network and externally. In either case, you will be able to access another container by its name (eg. `php`,`solr`,or `traefik` in this case) on the exposed port from another container.

Comment: Thats what I thought too... error logs say: `HTTP request failed, Could not resolve host: solr.projectname.docker.localhost` from the application.

Comment: What port is your solr container listening on? You need to `expose` that port in your docker-compose definition at the very least for other containers to access it. Then you would access your solr container on: `http://solr:port`. If you don't expose the port, then your Traefik container won't be able to talk to it.

Comment: Ah shoot, I guess I used the wrong port. It appears to work now (as container name) and gets resolved. Thanks!